# Handling input changes in mobx

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

Let's say that I have two forms, each related to a seperate mobx store.  One form is for Client info (first name, last name etc), and the other for Employee info.  Each form obviously has multiple inputs that update the observables in the related store.

In this example I have an action in each store that takes an event and based on the name, updates the value:

```
@action handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this[e.target.name] = e.target.value
}
```

Is there a way to abstract this action into a helper file, something that would contain common actions, instead of retyping this again and again?

Thanks in advance, I'm pretty new to this as you can imagine.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Nicholas! I personally don't think repeating the `handleInputChange` method above in each store that needs it is that bad.

Comment: Are you using React?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to handle the question. In my project, I just wrote an HOC(Higher-Order Component) to do that.

```
export default function asForm(MyComponent, formDataProp) {
    return @observer class Form extends Component {
        // constructor, etc.

        updateProperty(key, value) {
            this.props[formDataProp][key] = value;
        }

        // some other functions like double click prevention, etc.

        render() {
            return (
                <MyComponent
                    {...this.props}
                    updateProperty={this.updateProperty}
                    // some other props
                />
            );
        }
    };
}
```

Then use the HOC like this:

```
@observer
class UserForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const { updateProperty, userInfo } = this.props;
        return (
            <div className="form-wrapper">
                <YourInputComponent
                    name="name"
                    updateProperty={updateProperty}
                    value={userInfo.name}
                    // other props
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

UserForm.propTypes = {
    userInfo: PropTypes.instanceOf(UserInfo),
    updateProperty: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default asForm(UserForm, 'userInfo');
```

I am not sure if this solution violates the rule that you should not assign values to props.